# Then the value of the integral $ \iint_{A} f(x) g(y) \,d x\, d y $

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, area

Let $A=\{(x, y): x+y \leq 3\}$. Then the value of the integral
$$
\iint_A f(x) g(y) \,d x\, d y
$$
equals
*where*
$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x & \text { if } x \in[0,2] \\ 0 & \text { if } x \notin[0,2]\end{array}\right.$

$g(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text { if } x \in[0,2] \\ 0 & \text { if } x \notin[0,2]\end{array}\right.$

**My approach:**

*by the form* ($\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b} = 1$) I am getting a triangle,
whose area should be $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot3 \cdot3$$
$$= \frac{9}{2}$$
**Am I correct?**

Comment: What are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$???

Comment: Check the definition of $g(y)$.

Comment: If $g(y)$ is supposed to be $1$ if $0<y<2$ and $0$ otherwise, you should draw the region of interest $\{(x,y):x+y<3,0<x<2,0<y<2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x) g(y)$ is non-zero only if $(x, y) \in [0,2]^2$, we can recast our domain of integration as
$$A' = [0,2]^2 \setminus T$$
where $T \subset [0,2]^2$ is the triangle with vertices at $(1, 2), (2, 2)$, and $(2, 1)$. It's convenient to evaluate the integral over the square and subtract this triangle, writing
$$\iint_A f(x) g(y) \; dx \, dy = \int_0^2 \int_0^2 f(x) g(y) \; dx \, dy - \int_1^2 \int_{3-x}^2 f(x) g(y) \; dy \, dx$$
The first integral on the RHS is straightforward,
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^2 x \; dx \, dy = 4$$
The second requires only slightly more work,
$$\int_1^2 x \int_{3-x}^2 \; dy \, dx = \int_1^2  x(x-1) \, dx = \int_0^1 (x^2 + x) \, dx = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{6}$$
and hence we obtain the final answer
$$\iint_A f(x) g(y) \; dx \, dy = 4 - \frac{5}{6} = \frac{19}{6}$$